# Multiple raw input buffer

Tags: c, winapi

Is there a way to have one raw input buffer per device?

So I would like to have a buffer for mouse and another one for keyboard.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You will have to convert WM_KEY* messages to WM_CHAR yourself, though.

Comment: You will have to buffer them yourself. Is the buffering provided by Windows enough ? It will "buffer" the messages sent to your WNDPROC, and you can split them with a filter. But it is not very separate and it is hardly raw.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is YES

The RAWINPUTDEVICE struct permits this via usUsagePage and usUsage

usUsagePage is a value for the type of device (this is a partial list below). 1 is for 'generic desktop controls' and covers all the usual input devices. The usUsage value specifies the device within the 'generic desktop controls' group.

```
1 - generic desktop controls // we use this
2 - simulation controls
3 - vr
4 - sport
5 - game
6 - generic device
7 - keyboard
8 - LEDs
9 - button
```

usUsage values when usUsagePage is 1:

```
0 - undefined
1 - pointer
2 - mouse
3 - reserved
4 - joystick
5 - game pad
6 - keyboard // we use this
7 - keypad
8 - multi-axis controller
9 - Tablet PC controls
```

I wrote [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/297312/Minimal-Key-Logger-using-RAWINPUT) on Code Project that may be helpful.